# Outline Jquery Chosen Select box that was dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

**Problem:**

I'm adding a [Chosen Select](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) box dynamically to a page.  Upon button click, I would like to outline the Chosen box in red.  I can do this already for input boxes and such by adding a class with the CSS below to the appropriate ID but the Chosen box's border never changes.

```
.redOutlineTextBox {
    border:2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

I know it's possible to change the outline color on the Chosen control because if I add the following CSS upon load of the page, all chosen boxes will outline as expected.

```
.chosen-container .chosen-single {
    border:2px solid #FF0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

The following fiddle sets up the example of two dynamically added Chosen select box and one input box.

**What I would like to happen:**

Upon clicking the button, the first chosen box and the input box should outline in red as the .redOutlineTextBox class is added to both of them but the last chosen box should not highlight.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyjv9d8j/7/)

**Things I've Tried:**

I've set the settings of the Chosen box inherit select classes.

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
    width: "30%",
    search_contains: true,
    no_results_text: "No Results Found",
    max_selected_options: 5,
    inherit_select_classes: true
});
```

According to the Chosen documentation, you can trigger an update.  Upon adding the .redOutlineTextBox class, I tried calling this update with no results.

```
$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to highlight the box you can do this:

```
$(".chosen-container input").addClass('redOutlineTextBox')
```

If you want to highlight all text input boxes regardless of other classes, do:

```
$("input[type='text']").addClass('redOutlineTextBox')
```

Comment: I clicked your fiddle and it does work. What browser are you using?

Comment: IE 11.  When you say it works, are you saying the chosen boxes highlight, or just the input box in the middle highlights?  The input box already highlights just by adding the .redOutlineTextBox class to #inputTest.

Comment: Of course the Chosen box. Try it in Chrome and see, it highlights all three boxes. I also tried it in IE11 and it highlights the first and second input boxes, which is strange.

Comment: The code in the fiddle is not what I wrote.
What I wrote is `$('.chosen-search input')`, the selector you used in the fiddle is something entirely different: `$("#chosenTest_chosen input")`

Comment: Sorry, that was me playing around with other version.  I did originally try your code.    With your code, it does work in Chrome.  Unfortunately, this for an intranet site and we can not use Chrome.  For IE11, for whatever reason, it doesn't work on my computer.  Maybe we're not on the same update level as you or something because with $('.chosen-search input').addClass('redOutlineTextBox'), the chosen box does not highlight.

Comment: I've updated the answer to an IE compatible selector. Try it :)

Comment: We tried it on 2 computers here in IE11, does not seem to work with the update.  Here is the updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/yyjv9d8j/10/

Comment: This exact fiddle works for me on Chrome and IE 11.0.9600.18314, update version 11.0.31 -- if you suspect IE is not up to date in your organization, contact whoever's in charge there and ask them to bring it up to date. Good luck.

Comment: Also - try the generic version I added in the edit: `"input[type='text']"` - it also works on IE11.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add the class to the #chosenTest select, but that element isn't actually visible. The visible element is just an input field. I don't know Chosen well enough to know if you can specify an id for that element, but I was able to add the class to it like this:

```
$("#chosenTest_chosen input").addClass('redOutlineTextBox');
```

Comment: You're correct in that the #chosenTest element is not visible but neither is the #inputTest element, and adding the class to #inputTest works, but doesn't work for the #chosenTest element.  The input element is also added dynamically.  I tried the above code and it does not work.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/yyjv9d8j/8/

Comment: Upon investigation, this does work, but only in Chrome, which we can't use for this internal intranet site.  It must work with IE11.